# GNU/Linux Date Command Ordinal Suffix

Tags: linux, unix, date, coreutils

The PHP [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function offers the ability to add an ordinal suffix for the day of the month, such as 'st', 'nd', 'rd', etc. Is it possible to achieve the same thing with the `date` command in Linux?

Comment: Perusing through the man page, I do not see any such option. You could easily write a function that will take the day and echo the format you are looking for using a statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think common `date` implementations cannot do this by themselves. You can request some custom format with a "wildcard" of your choice and then process it. Example:

```
LC_ALL=C date '+%B %eXX %Y' | sed -e 's/11XX/11th/' -e 's/12XX/12th/' -e 's/13XX/13th/' -e 's/1XX/1st/' -e 's/2XX/2nd/' -e 's/3XX/3rd/' -e 's/XX/th/'
```

I used `LC_ALL=C` so the command can be tested regardless of locale.

---

To see how this `sed` command processes various dates with "wildcards", run this:

```
sed -e 's/11XX/11th/' -e 's/12XX/12th/' -e 's/13XX/13th/' -e 's/1XX/1st/' -e 's/2XX/2nd/' -e 's/3XX/3rd/' -e 's/XX/th/' << EOF
October  1XX 2019
October  2XX 2019
October  3XX 2019
October  4XX 2019
October 10XX 2019
October 11XX 2019
October 12XX 2019
October 13XX 2019
October 14XX 2019
October 20XX 2019
October 21XX 2019
October 22XX 2019
October 23XX 2019
October 24XX 2019
October 30XX 2019
October 31XX 2019
EOF
```

---

Note `%e` pads single digit numbers with leading space characters. You may or may not want this. Some implementations of `date` may allow you to avoid this (`date` from GNU coreutils? use `%-d`). A portable fix to my example is to expand `sed` with `-e 's/  / /'`.

Answer (score -1):

My solution here is to pipe:
`sed -e 's/ of/th of/' -e 's/2th/2nd/' -e 's/\([^1]\)3th/\13rd/' -e 's/\([^1]\)1th/\11st/'`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Shouldn't it be 11th/12th (eleventh/twelfth)  instead of 12nd/22nd?